# Filtering by the sum of sub measures

Tags: tableau-api

Very new to Tableau. For work, I am instructed to do mapping by zip codes, and to find a way to have the zip codes filtered by the count (for example, I toggle to 5,000, I should have my map display what zip codes contained 5,000 customers).

I plotted the Longitude and Latitude, and I want to filter by zip code in this fashion with color. I tried creating a filter by zip code, and it is just showing where the zip codes are geographically.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `calculated field` which counts (`count`) zip-codes, you can then apply that `calculated field` onto the `Color` tab to get each zip-code colorized.